# "Search Folders" on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, search

How do you create a Search Folder on Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like on Vista:

- Navigate to **Start -> Search**
- Type your desired query in the search box
- After the results of your search are shown, click **See more results** to open the search results in explorer.
- Click **Save Search** in this new window

Windows Vista:

[image]

Windows 7:

[image]

Comment: +1 @JohnT, but you have to mention that, after typing the search terms into the search box and after the results appear, the "See more results" link has to be clicked to open the search results in a Windows Explorer window, which will have the "Save Search" toolbar button.

Answer (score 0):

Either go to `C:\users\your_name` or press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `%userprofile%`, then double click on the folder "Searches".

All your saved searches are here - This should be the same as the "Search Folder" feature of Vista.

To create a new saved search, the simplest way is simply to run a search (from the top right hand corner) or click the start orb and type your search term then click at the bottom `See more results". You should then see the option`Save search` and it will save as a "Search Folder"

[image]

[image]