# Windows 7 advanced search

Tags: windows-7, search, windows-search

I was trying to follow the answer @ ["Search Folders" on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/83594/search-folders-on-windows-7)

Unfortunately, those instructions make absolutely no sense.  First of all, There is no Start -> Search.
Secondly, I don't have any option for advanced search.  How the heck do I get those options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Start` -> `Start Search` simply implies typing into the search bar when you hit the Start button. Then, when search results begin to appear, press `Search everywhere`.

At this point, a "Search Results" dialog will appear. From here, you can locate the button "Save Search" from the toolbar to save the search as a "Search Folder", which will always present the files within as results of the specified search query.

This goes for both Vista and Windows 7. I hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.top-windows-tutorials.com/windows-7-tutorial15.html) is a nice video tutorial for Windows 7 search. To improve the search capabilities of Windows 7 you can look into [IFilters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFilter). I know you probably don't want third party software but you can always consider [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/). BTW I up voted Paul as his answer answers your question. These are merely suggestions.